# PySpark - multiple union on DataFrame getting slower

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I encountered a problem with DataFrame union in PySpark (version 2.4.3). 
When doing union on multiple data frames, each subsequent union is getting slower.

Similar issue has already been registered and marked as solved in Spark version 1.4: 
[SPARK-12691](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12691).

Here is sample code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from time import perf_counter

sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = sc.parallelize([(x, 2*x) for x in range(10)]).toDF()
df_all = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), df.schema)
for i in range(2000):
    t1 = perf_counter()
    df_all = df_all.union(df)
    print(f"{i} - {round(perf_counter() - t1, 3)}s")
```

Output:

```
0 - 0.036s                                                                      
1 - 0.007s
2 - 0.009s
3 - 0.01s
4 - 0.009s
5 - 0.014s
6 - 0.01s
7 - 0.013s
8 - 0.015s
9 - 0.01s
...
1990 - 0.091s
1991 - 0.085s
1992 - 0.094s
1993 - 0.091s
1994 - 0.081s
1995 - 0.076s
1996 - 0.085s
1997 - 0.082s
1998 - 0.085s
1999 - 0.083s
```

If the issue is solved then why the above code is slowing down?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing union every time `df` with itself, meaning that it becomes twice large at every iteration. At the last iteration you get 10*(2^21)=20971520 elements. So, the above timings are expected.

EDIT: you entirely changed the code. Now you are doing union every time with the original `df` of 10 elements. At the last, 1999'th iteration the size will be 2000*10 = 20000 elements. So, once again, the timings are expected.

Comment: You're right. I updated the example. Of course, the resulting DataFrame is still getting larger (linearily), but as I understood from SPARK-12691 the time shouldn't grow at all.